# Basic sum and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I've got a basic SQL query question. I am using SQL Server. I am a complete beginner in SQL.

I've got 3 tables. Ultimately, all I want to produce is a list of the 100 hotels (with their ID, name and place) with the most sales.

So I know I need to group by `hotel_id`, sum up all the booking values, and then take the top 100. However, I just cannot figure out how to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The tables are as per below:

```
PLACE(
    place_id,
    name
)

HOTEL(
    hotel_id,
    hotel_name
)

BOOKING(
    booking_id,
    hotel_id,
    booking_value
)
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data? Also, how does `PLACE` relate to the other tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming `PLACE` is supposed to have a `HOTEL_ID` to link it to the other tables.

selects top 100 after ordering by the SUM of the booking value

this is joining all tables based on `HOTEL_ID`

```
Select top 100 H.HOTEL_ID, H.HOTEL_NAME, P.NAME, 
SUM( B.BOOKING_VALUE)
from HOTEL H 
inner join BOOKING B on B.HOTEL_ID = H.HOTEL_ID 
inner join PLACE P on P.HOTEL_ID = H.HOTEL_ID
group by H.HOTEL_ID, H.HOTEL_NAME, P.NAME
order by SUM(B.BOOKING_VALUE) desc
```

Comment: Yes sorry you are right the PLACE table has the hotel_id in it. Thanks very much too! Most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the booking_value of BOOKING is reference to the place_id of PLACE. You can  use this way to get the most sales：

```
SELECT TOP 100 H.hotel_id, H.hotel_name, P.name
FROM HOTEL H 
inner join BOOKING B ON B.hotel_id = H.hotel_id 
inner join PLACE P ON P.place_id = B.booking_value
GROUP BY H.hotel_id, H.hotel_name, P.name
order by COUNT(*) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 100 h.hotel_id,h.hotel_name,p.name,SUM(b.booking_value)AS [Total Sales] FROM HOTEL h INNER JOIN PLACE p ON p.place_id=h.place_id
INNER JOIN BOOKING b ON b.hotel_id=h.hotel_id
GROUP BY h.hotel_id,h.hotel_name,p.name
ORDER BY [Total Sales] DESC
```